# Internacionalização do bg-image por CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, localização

Eu tenho um projeto em Rails que necessita de imagens diferentes para cada linguagem, entretanto e imagem é puxada do CSS e eu não posso mudar isso. Como trocar a imagem de acordo com o idioma escolhido?

```
  background: url("/caminho/imagem.jpg");
```

edit:
recebi muitas respostas e esqueci de fornecer alguma infos, meu ruby é o 1.8.7 e o rails é o 3, não é aconselhável eu criar outro arquivo de css e, apesar de não ter certeza, meu css não é o 2 nem qualquer outro mais recente.

edit2:
e estou usando haml ao invés de html

Comment: Você não pode editar o CSS, por exemplo, criar outras classes?

Comment: não tenho autorização para isso :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o que funcionou foi criar 2 blocos de código dentro do mesmo arquivo de css:

```
class-br{
  atributos-br
}
class-en{
  atributos-en
}
```

e usar o atributo class no haml atribuindo o locale como variável:

```
%li{:class=> "class-#{params[:locale]}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Em *PHP* usa-se pacotes de tradução para cada idioma:

```
language/
     pt.php
     en.php
     es.php
```

Você pode criar um *CSS* apenas com as imagens para cada idioma. Separe as imagens em um css-idioma.css e carregue o que for referente à linguagem.

```
css/
     pt.css
     en.css
     es.css

css/pt.css background: url("/caminho/imagem.jpg"); // background escrito em português
css/en.css background: url("/caminho/imagem.jpg"); // background escrito em ingles
css/en.css background: url("/caminho/imagem.jpg"); // background escrito em espanhol
```

Comment: Tem um *typo* ali no `tanslate/`, mas creio que em geral essa pasta é `lang/` ou `language/`...

Comment: Faltou um "R" :). lang, language, i18n, translate e afins, acho que é mais questão pessoal. No meu caso uso uma classe *i18n* então os packs acompanham o nome para facilitar *app/i18n/...*.

Comment: É, `i18n/` é bonito :)

Comment: muito obrigado :D

Comment: @André Ventura, se resolveu, marque uma das respostas.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a [excelente resposta do @PapaCharlie](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32239/7261):

Depois que você criou os diferentes CSS para cada língua, utilize o seguinte código para dizer ao Rails que esses CSS também devem ser precompilados para produção:

```
# /config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["imagens.pt-BR.css", "imagens.en.css"]
```

Leia mais:

- [Guia Oficial sobre assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

Comment: Fiquei na teoria apenas, não sei nada de Rails, até vou dar uma olhada no link.